# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'overloaded-function' to '...'

Tags: c++, boost, function-pointers

Now I am try to use boost bind & `mem_fn`.
But there's a problem to bind overloaded-function.
How to resolve compile error of follow codes?

```
boost::function< void( IF_MAP::iterator ) > bmf = std::mem_fun1< void, IF_MAP, IF_MAP::iterator >( &IF_MAP::erase );
boost::function< void( IF_MAP::iterator ) > bmf = boost::mem_fn< void, IF_MAP, IF_MAP::iterator >( &IF_MAP::erase );
```

The main purpose is to compile follow codes

```
IF_MAP M;
boost::function< void( IF_MAP::iterator ) > bmf = boost::bind(
    boost::mem_fn< void, IF_MAP, IF_MAP::iterator >( &IF_MAP::erase ),
    &M, _1 );
M.insert( IF_MAP::value_type( 1, 1.f ) ); M.insert( IF_MAP::value_type( 2, 2.f ) );
bmf( 2 );
```

The compile error messages are like this...

> error C2665: 'boost::mem_fn' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
>   could be 'boost::_mfi::mf1 boost::mem_fn::iterator>(R (__thiscall std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::* )(A1))'
>   or 'boost::_mfi::cmf1 boost::mem_fn::iterator>(R (__thiscall std::map<_Kty,_Ty>::* )(A1) const)'

P.S.
As U know, std::map has 3 overloaded erase member function

1. `void erase(iterator _Where)`
2. `size_type erase(const key_type& _Keyval)`
3. `void erase(iterator _First, iterator _Last)`

   2nd function can be binded easily, but others not.

*Edit*
To describe my question in more detail:

Actually, I want to make deferred function call.
When I meet return code of function, then it's time to scope out, so deferred function should be called.

Now I am refactoring some legacy codes. Nowdays, I usually see like this pattern of codes.
(Actual codes are more complex but almost same as follows)
Duplicated `erase()` calls are scattered in this function.

```
typedef map< int, float > IF_MAP;

bool DoAndPopOld( IF_MAP& M, int K )
{
    IF_MAP::iterator Itr = M.find( K );
    if ( Itr == M.end() ) return false;

    if ( K < 10 ) 
    {
        M.erase( Itr ); // erase call is here...
        return false;
    }

    if ( 100 < K )
    {
        // Do something
        M.erase( Itr ); // and here...
        return true;
    }

    // Do something
    M.erase( Itr ); // and also here!

    return true;
}
```

So, I wanna refactoring above code like this...

```
class ScopedOutCaller
{
private:
    boost::function< void() > F;
public:
    ScopedOutCaller( boost::function< void() > _F ) : F(_F) {}
    ~ScopedOutCaller() { F(); } // deferred function call
};

bool DoAndPopNew( IF_MAP& M, int K )
{
    IF_MAP::iterator Itr = M.find( K );
    if ( Itr == M.end() ) return false;

    // Make deferred call, so I do not consider calling erase function anymore.
    ScopedOutCaller SOC( boost::bind( &IF_MAP::erase ), &M, Itr );

    if ( K < 10 ) 
    {
        // M.erase( Itr ); <-- unnecessary
        return false;
    }
    if ( 100 < K )
    {
        // Do something
        // M.erase( Itr ); <-- unnecessary
        return true;
    }

    // Do something
    // M.erase( Itr ); <-- unnecessary
    return true;
}
```

But, as I asked... compile errors are occurred.
The long and the short of what I want to do is how to defer function call.
Please tell me the way to make deferred call.
Thanks.

Comment: I moved the info from your "answer" into the question, where it's supposed to be. If you have additional info, please edit it into the question. If you post it as an answer, it just confuses (and more importantly, people won't see if before answering)

Comment: Well, do you only care about VC or not?

Comment: @George I usually use MSVS, but if you have any idea, please tell me something. thanks.

Comment: So, doesn't the type to cast to for VC i gave solve it? If not, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map`s member function `erase()` is overloaded, thus you have to manually disambiguate - see the [Boost.Bind FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded).

E.g. for the `size_type erase(const key_type&)` overload:

```
typedef IF_MAP::size_type (IF_MAP::*EraseType2)(const IF_MAP::key_type&);
boost::function<void (const IF_MAP::key_type&)> bmf2;
bmf2 = boost::bind((EraseType2)&IF_MAP::erase, &M, _1);
```

To select the other versions simply change the type you are casting to, e.g.:

```
// 1. void erase(iterator position) :
typedef void (IF_MAP::*EraseType1)(IF_MAP::iterator);
boost::function<void (IF_MAP::iterator)> bmf1;
bmf1 = boost::bind((EraseType1)&IF_MAP::erase, &M, _1);

// 3. void erase(iterator first, iterator last) :
typedef void (IF_MAP::*EraseType3)(IF_MAP::iterator, IF_MAP::iterator);
boost::function<void (IF_MAP::iterator, IF_MAP::iterator)> bmf3;
bmf3 = boost::bind((EraseType3)&IF_MAP::erase, &M, _1, _2);
```

Sadly Visual Studio is non-conforming to C++03 here (once again...) and you have to use the following two forms:

```
typedef IF_MAP::iterator (IF_MAP::*EraseType1)(IF_MAP::const_iterator);
typedef IF_MAP::iterator (IF_MAP::*EraseType3)(IF_MAP::const_iterator,
                                               IF_MAP::const_iterator);
```

With VC8 and VC9 you can solve that problem by using [`_HAS_STRICT_CONFORMANCE`](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.stl/2005-10/msg00030.html), but this breaks again with VC10 as C++0x changes the `erase()` overloads to the forms used by Dinkumware (see [N3092, 23.4.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf)).
For portability i'd go for using a wrapper function instead to get around these annoying problems; if however you only care about VC just use the types i provided above.

To execute the resulting functors at block exit, the simplest way is to use [Boosts `shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#on_block_exit) or a similar scope guard. E.g. for the VC specific cast:

```
typedef IF_MAP::iterator (IF_MAP::*EraseType)(IF_MAP::const_iterator);
boost::shared_ptr<void> guard(static_cast<void*>(0),
                              boost::bind((EraseType)&IF_MAP::erase, &M, Itr));
```

Comment: Thans for your answer. Yeh.. as u mentioned, erase member function can be binded(I did it). But I wanna bind other overloaded function...like, void erase(iterator _Where) or void erase(iterator _First, iterator _Last). ^^; Do u have any idea?

Comment: @codevania: Sure, it is completely the same procedure - simply change the type you are casting to.

Comment: Thank you very much Georg. But above codes U suggested are not compiled because of 'type-cast error'.

Comment: My Compiler version is MSVS2005: Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86

Comment: @code: Compiles fine for me with GCC & Boost 1.42, so you have to be more specific.

Comment: Exactly same error message is occurred on MSVS2010. So there is no way unless I user GCC compiler. T_T... Thanks any way. How kind of U to help.

Comment: error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'EraseType2' (MSVS2010 & boost 1.43)

Comment: Interesting:  in C++0x, a lot of member functions that weren't previously overloaded are now overloaded with moving versions (e.g., `vector::push_back`).  I suppose that if anyone is actually relying on those functions to not be overloaded is in for a surprise when they try to compile their code with a C++0x compiler.  I guess that break in backwards compatibility was considered minor compared to the utility of the added overloads.

Comment: @James: As long as it results in compile errors instead of silent misbehaviour i think its fine. But changing the signatures of the existing overloads is a bit annoying portability-wise.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was deducing template argument if I use boost::mem_fn. And another one was inappropriate function signature. It's o.k if I use erase() that returning iterator not void.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ScopedOutCaller SOC(boost::bind(static_cast< IF_MAP::iterator (IF_MAP::*)(IF_MAP::const_iterator) >(&IF_MAP::erase), &M, Itr));
```

And for Visual Studio 2005:

```
ScopedOutCaller SOC(boost::bind(static_cast< IF_MAP::iterator (IF_MAP::*)(IF_MAP::iterator) >(&IF_MAP::erase), &M, Itr));
```

Comment: I see... Correct signature is "IF_MAP::iterator (IF_MAP::*)(IF_MAP::iterator)" not "void (IF_MAP::*)(IF_MAP::iterator)"